# CICLOS DE VIDA DE ACTIVIDADES

Tags: android, android-studio, ciclo-de-vida

tengo una aplicacion en android studio con 30 cronometros que son para cada usuario, la idea es poder llevarle el control del tiempo a cada usuario desde una tablet, pero se me presenta el incoveniente de que inicio el cronometro con la informacion para el Usuario A y cuando regreso al listado de usuarios (que esta en otra actividad) para seleccionar otro usuario (usuario B) e iniciarle el cronometro, si ingreso de nuevo a la vista del usuario A el cronometro y toda la informacion se ha perdido. ¿Que deseo? poder iniciar los cronometros de todos y que el cronometro no se detenga hasta que yo no le diga detener. Cualquier informacion que me puedan suministrar me seria de mucha ayuda. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Cuando inicies un cronómetro puedes guardar en shared preferences el usuario, supongamos usuario A, y la hora en que se inició su cronómetro. Cuando ingreses de nuevo, en el onResume, consulta las shared preferences en busca de la hora de inicio de ese cronómetro, si tiene un valor entonces calcula el tiempo que ha pasado desde que se inició restando la hora actual menos la hora de inicio. Así por cada usuario tendrás guardada la hora de inicio de sus cronómetros.

Comment: Puedes usar alguna opción de almacenamiento de Android para guardar los valores y obtenerlos en OnCreate(). Te sugerimos revisar [ask] para que sepas como realizar preguntas en el sitio y obtengas la ayuda requerida, saludos.